# Survey function in Android App

Tags: android, survey, diagramming

i want to implement a survey function in my app. There should be a 4 alternative answers and a diagramm which ilustrates the results. Has anyone an idea how i could do this? Maybe is there even a Library? I am thankful for every suggestion.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use a Webview within your app and an existing survey service like Survey monkey.

https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/mobile-surveys/

In addition to this they also have a developer platform if you want to do more than the average survey: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/Home

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will definetly try it