# Android: user survey mechanism without a dedicated server?

Tags: android, google-analytics

There is a survey activity, for simplicity with the only choice like: 'Are you satisfied with the application (Yes/No)' and a Send button.

Now I want to give my users the possibility to fill and send such a survey to me.

I do not want, however, to setup my own dedicated server to process the requests, neither use any 3rd party engines which would require my user be online at the time of sending the survey. Also, composing mail seems to be no option, too.

I'm thinking of using Google Analytics, defining custom event for the survey sending together with data.

I'm not sure, however if this would be a good approach, that is, if people out there indeed do like that. Are there, possibly, any other approaches?

Comment: Google Analytics is a third-party server. You said that you do not want to use a third-party server. Hence, you do not want to use Google Analytics. And since every server is either your own server or a third-party server, you seem to want to use the Internet without using the Internet.

Comment: Note that I did not downvote your question. That being said, I am not terribly surprised that it got a downvote.

Comment: Appreciate the joke. I meant I do not want to use anything which would require internet connection at the time of sending the survey. Don't want to invent my own mchanism, too. So was asking if GA would be suitable for that never worked with it before. Sorry, I wasn't quite clear, I've edited the question. Downvoting is ok, why not as long as someone answers.

Comment: Agree with CommonsWare here, either you're going to use the internet or not.  And since you want the results transferred to you from them, that will require the internet.  I guess technically you could set up SMS communication or something but that's sounds like overkill for what you're doing.  I think understanding the reason behind your requirement of not requiring an internet connection when sending the survey would help with finding a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked a similar question to this recently : [Survey function in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061080/survey-function-in-android-app/26061548#26061548)

How about possibly using something simple like Survey Monkey.

https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/mobile-surveys/

In addition to this they also have a developer platform if you want to do more than the average survey: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/Home

Disclaimer: I don't work at survey monkey

Comment: My user then will need internet connection at the moment of sending the survey?

Comment: @Alex yes they will, if there's no connection then you would have to handle those cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a very simple survey, Id suggest asking the question inside the activity, and having the user email it to you. You can easily use the email intent for this. I personally use it for feedback in a few of my apps.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

as an alternative, you could setup a google form with the survey questions, and then build a simple webview activity that points to the google form. I have also used this in a few cases and it works well. The only problem with using a google form, is that you cant really customize the look, so it won't match your app well.

Comment: Well, my alternative will still work if you would prefer a webview.